# Local Nominatim server returns incorrect place with GPS lookup

Tags: openstreetmap

I am trying to run a local Nominatim server with a smaller dataset that only includes cities, towns and villages similar to [this Stackoverflow](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185793/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-all-cities-in-the-world-from-openstreetmap) question. My goal is to look up which GPS coordinates correlate to what city, I have tried creating a smaller dataset with two different commands:

```
./osmosis --read-pbf planet-latest.osm.pbf --tf accept-nodes place=city,town,village --tf reject-relations --tf reject-ways --lp --write-pbf planet-excerpt.osm.pbf
```

and also

```
./osmosis --read-pbf planet-latest.osm.pbf --tf accept-nodes place=city,town,village --tf accept-relations --tf accept-ways --lp --write-pbf planet-excerpt2.osm.pbf
```

The problem is that the reverse lookup on my local Nominatim server returns a different place than the official one, I have included some examples of the returned json outputs.

[Place 1 local](https://pastebin.com/PuTitv8n) (Chillum) vs [Place 1 official](https://pastebin.com/YHJujfnc) (Washington)

[Place 2 local](https://pastebin.com/N6kju0sT) (Getafe) vs [Place 2 official](https://pastebin.com/xr5KSNfW) (Madrid)

[Place 3 local](https://pastebin.com/8RepvwcY) (Gatineau) vs [Place 3 official](https://pastebin.com/LpNSSg7f) (Ottawa)

There seems to be an issue with the correct detection of the bounding boxes, how can I improve this? I'd rather not import the whole planet and if I have to go that route can I drop information afterwards without impacting the reverse lookup?

Comment: Just for clarification, with 'reverse lookup' you mean inputting coordinates and getting back the place?

Comment: What coordinates are you using to get place 1?

Comment: Yes, for example this api call which is what I used for place 1 `reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=38.89984130859375&lon=-77.0086669921875`

Comment: Then there seem to be to questions in your question. 1. The wrong place is returned for a given set of coordinates. 2. Something about the bounding boxes, is that correct? Also, are you sure that whashington is actually in your file, that it is not just taking the nearest place to your coordinates in the absence of washington?

Comment: 1. Yes
2. This was just a speculation on my side.


Searching for Washington yields results, if I click on details I receive correct information but searching for the city centres coordinates returns a different place. This also isn't universal with all searches, some cites like Berlin work properly but Munich for example doesn't, the latter has other towns close to it that seem to interfere with the GPS lookup

Comment: My first hunch would be that it has to do with the spatial index, as the places are not half a world apart, but are somewhat close to one another. Also, I noted that the coordinates are to 13 or 8 decimal places accurate, which is [quite accurate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees). But that is a sidenote. Is the .osm.pbf further processed before it serves as backend of your reserve-geocode server?

Comment: It is not further processed but imported into Nominatim afterwards.